# How to find position of point that is x unit distant from AB line segment and y unit distant from BC line segment?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, geometry

[image: Representation image]

I am trying to calculate coordinates of point P, which is x units distant from AB line segment and y units distant from BC line segment.

Edit:
I am trying to write code for general solution. 
As parameters, I have three points (coordinates) A, B and C and also two values for distance x and y.

Comment: It very much depends on the corner case you need to handle, and whether your "distance to the line segment" is the same as "distance to the line that contains the segment".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's translate all points `A,B,C` by `(-BX, -BY)` to set coordinate origin to `B`, new points are `a, 0, c`, and I would rename you distances to `dc` and `da`.

New coordinates

```
cy = CY - BY
cx = CX - BX
ay = AY - BY
ax = AX - BX
```

Then line `0c` will have equation

```
(-cy * x + cx * y) / Sqrt(cx*cx +cy*cy) = 0
```

line `0a` will have equation

```
(-ay * x + ax * y) / Sqrt(ax*ax +ay*ay) = 0
```

Let's `lc = Sqrt(cx*cx +cy*cy)` and `la = Sqrt(ax*ax +ay*ay)` (lengths of `BC` and `BA` segments)

If point `p=(px, py)` lies at `dc` distance from line `0c`, and at `da` distance from line `0a`, then

```
Abs(-cy * px + cx * py) = dc * lc
Abs(-ay * px + ax * py) = da * la
```

If your points always form counterclockwise order of `BC, BP, BA` rays, you may use this sign combination only and find single solution:

```
-cy * px + cx * py = dc * lc
-ay * px + ax * py = - da * la
```

Solve this linear system for `px` and `py`, in the end shift coordinates back by `BX`, `BY`

```
PX = px + BX
PY = py + BY
```

P.S. In extra case `angle ABC=180` system has no solution for `da<>dc` or infinite number of solutions for `da=dc`

Comment: Note: for angle ABC = 180, there's no solution if the two distances are unequal. If the two distances are equal, then there are infinite solutions (any point on either of two lines parallel to ABC at that distance from it).